# Style WM(T)S layers from a QGIS server into a Cesium imagery component

Tags: qgis-server, cesium, vue.js

I have a [QGIS server docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/qgis-server/) which is serving some aerial images (raster data) on one virtual machine.

I have an other virtual machine which holds a [Cesium](https://cesium.com/) cartographic web application in [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/).

I am wondering if it's possible for example, to dynamically apply different styles to, e.g., a Cesium [WebMapServiceImageryProvider](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/WebMapServiceImageryProvider.html) which URL parameter points to the QGIS server available layers, as if I was styling these layers directly in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an SLD parameter with a URL reference to a public SLD file, or a SLD_BODY parameter with a urlencoded SLD.

Comment: Do SLD files apply on raster data?

Comment: It can do https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html